# How To: Sprite to Trace a .PNG in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

If this makes sense, I would want to know a way to let duplicate sprites to trace the outline of a .PNG image at an equal spacing margin.

**For Example**

I have an image of a tree-like shaped triangle, and I have a sprite that is set to image name "ornament" which would make ornaments go around the tree, and tips?

Comment: Go look at sprite kit documentation

Comment: @Roecrew I don't think there is anything in the documentation that describes this (at least for SKSpriteNode), or at least nothing obvious. If you could supply the link to the answer, it would be more helpful than just telling him to look for it.

Comment: Without reading every pixel this will be difficult. Could you provide a CGPath instead of an image?